# Paste position over several slides doesn't carry through, will only paste in the middle of slide

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

I'm having a bit of trouble getting the tables that are copied from Excel to be pasted anywhere else other than the middle of the PowerPoint slide.

I need to make the columns looks a uniform table in the end. I haven't been able to figure out how to aggregate all non-contiguous columns into one table, so I will paste each column one by one and move each entry by a couple of digits.

Right now I have it where the columns on the first slide are pasted at `myShape.Left = 66` and `myShape.Top = 152`, but after the first slide they just go back to pasting in the middle of the slide.

Any ideas?

```
Public Sub averageScoreRelay()
    ' 1. Run from PPT and open an Excel file
    ' 2. Start at slide 1 and find a box that contains the words "iq_", if it has those words then it will have numbers after it like so "iq_43" or "iq_43, iq_56, iq_72".
    ' 3. find those words and numbers in the opened Excel file. Needs to recognize that ", " means there is another entry.
    ' 3. Copy column containing words from ppt ie. "iq_43"
    ' 4. Paste a Table into ppt with those values
    ' 5. Do this for every slide

    'Create variables
    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
    Dim xlWB As Excel.Workbook
    Dim pptSlide As Slide
    Dim fileName As String
    Dim Shpe As Shape
    Dim pptText As String
    Dim strArray As String
    Dim pptPres As Object
    Dim PowerPointApp As Object
    Dim iq_Array
    Dim arrayLoop As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim myShape As Object

    ' Create new excel instance and open relevant workbook
    Set xlApp = New Excel.Application
    Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\pinlop\Desktop\Gate\Macro\averageScores\pptxlpratice\dummyavgscore.xlsx", True, False)  'Open relevant workbook
    If xlWB Is Nothing Then ' may not need this if statement. check later.
        MsgBox ("Error retrieving Average Score Report, Check file path")
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Is PowerPoint already opened?
    'Set PowerPointApp = GetObject(class:="PowerPoint.Application")

    'Make PPT visible
    Set pptPres = PowerPoint.ActivePresentation

    'Loop through each pptSlide and check for IQ text box, grab avgScore values and create pptTable
    For Each pptSlide In pptPres.Slides
        'searches through shapes in the slide
        For Each Shpe In pptSlide.Shapes
            'Identify if there is text frame
            If Shpe.HasTextFrame Then
                'Identify if there's text in text frame
                If Shpe.TextFrame.HasText Then
                    pptText = Shpe.TextFrame.TextRange
                    If InStr(1, pptText, "iq_") > 0 Then 'Identify if within text there is "iq_" All IQ's have to be formatted like this "iq_42, iq_43" for now
                        iq_Array = Split(pptText, ", ")               'Use function below to Set iq_Array to an array of all iq_'s in the text box
                        size = UBound(iq_Array) - LBound(iq_Array)
                        For arrayLoop = 0 To size
                            For i = 1 To 5
                                If i = 1 And arrayLoop = 0 Then
                                    xlWB.Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns(1).Copy
                                    pptSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=ppPasteHTML, Link:=msoFalse
                                    Set myShape = pptSlide.Shapes(pptSlide.Shapes.Count)
                                    'Set position:
                                    myShape.Left = 66
                                    myShape.Top = 152
                                ElseIf xlWB.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, i) = iq_Array(arrayLoop) And i <> 1 Then
                                    xlWB.Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns(i).Copy
                                    pptSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=ppPasteHTML, Link:=msoFalse
                                    Set myShape = pptSlide.Shapes(pptSlide.Shapes.Count)
                                    'Set position:
                                    myShape.Left = 66
                                    myShape.Top = 152
                                End If
                            Next i
                        Next arrayLoop
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next Shpe
    Next pptSlide
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to aggregate everything by creating a new sheet and pasting each column individually onto that sheet then copying that into PowerPoint.

Also, to make it paste where i want it to on the slide, I made sure to make VBA `.Select` everything.

```
With xlWB.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    colNumb = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
End With

xlWB.Worksheets.Add After:=xlWB.ActiveSheet

'Make pptPres the ppt active
Set pptPres = PowerPoint.ActivePresentation

'Loop through each pptSlide and check for IQ text box, grab avgScore values and create pptTable
For Each pptSlide In pptPres.Slides
    'searches through shapes in the slide
    pptSlide.Select
    For Each Shpe In pptSlide.Shapes
        'Identify if there is text frame
        k = 1
        If Shpe.HasTextFrame Then
            'Identify if there's text in text frame
            If Shpe.TextFrame.HasText Then
                pptText = Shpe.TextFrame.TextRange
                If InStr(1, pptText, "iq_") > 0 Then 'Identify if within text there is "iq_" All IQ's have to be formatted like this "iq_42, iq_43" for now
                    iq_Array = Split(pptText, ", ")               'set iq_Array as an array of the split iq's
                    size = UBound(iq_Array) - LBound(iq_Array)
                    For arrayLoop = 0 To size   'loop for each iq_array
                        For i = 1 To colNumb    'loops for checking each column
                            If i = 1 And arrayLoop = 0 Then  'Copies the first column for every slide
                                If Len(iq_Array(arrayLoop)) < 4 Then GoTo Line2
                                xlWB.Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns(1).Copy   'copy column
                                xlWB.Worksheets("Sheet2").Paste Destination:=xlWB.Worksheets("Sheet2").Columns(1)
                            ElseIf xlWB.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, i) = iq_Array(arrayLoop) And i <> 1 Then 'if iq in ppt = iq in xl and if not the first cell then execute
                                k = k + 1
                                xlWB.Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns(i).Copy
                                xlWB.Worksheets("Sheet2").Paste Destination:=xlWB.Worksheets("Sheet2").Columns(k)
                            End If
                        Next i
Line2:
                    Next arrayLoop
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next Shpe
'calculate last row and last column
With xlWB.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    lRows = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    lCols = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    If lRows = .Cells(1, 1).End(xlUp).Row And lCols = .Cells(1, 1).End(xlToLeft).Column Then
        GoTo Line1
    End If
        .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(lRows, lCols)).Copy
End With
        pptSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=ppPasteHTML, Link:=msoFalse
        Set myShape = pptSlide.Shapes(pptSlide.Shapes.Count)
        'Set position:
        myShape.Left = -200
        myShape.Top = 200
        xlWB.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:P10").Clear
Line1:
Next pptSlide

xlWB.Worksheets("Sheet2").Delete

End Sub
```